# how can we update dynamodb table based on index(not based on primary has and range key)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

how can we update dynamodb table based on index(not based on primary has and range key).
I have a index created by name `key_id-index`
and hash is `asset_id` and range is `hit_id`.
i want to update the table based on `key_id-index` because i wouldn't know those while updating.

```
var paramsu = {
  TableName: 'asset',
  //IndexName: 'key_id-index',
  Key: { // The primary key of the item (a map of attribute name to AttributeValue)

    asset_id: { S: 'a' },
    hit_id: { S: 'h' }
    // more attributes...
  },
  AttributeUpdates: { // The attributes to update (map of attribute name to AttributeValueUpdate)

    key_id: {
      Action: 'PUT', // PUT (replace)
                     // ADD (adds to number or set)
                     // DELETE (delete attribute or remove from set)
      Value: { S: 'updated1' }
    }
    // more attribute updates: ...
  },

  ReturnValues: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | ALL_OLD | UPDATED_OLD | ALL_NEW | UPDATED_NEW)
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
  ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'NONE' // optional (NONE | SIZE)
};
db.updateItem(paramsu, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot write to a GSI.

Your only option is to first read from the GSI, get the attribute values that are are your keys (they are always projected onto the index, see [GSI.Projections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections)), and then write your data back to the table.