# how to update Db items with secondary index in Dynamo Db?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I Have one table users in which primary index is email key but also secondary index is made i.e _id, so how to  update on the items with _id as criteria?
Below is the code.

```
let params = {
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    Key:{
        '_id' : event.id
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set phoneNumber = :phoneNumber",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":phoneNumber": event.phoneNumber
    },
    ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW"
};

documentClient.update(params, function(err, updated) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(updated, null, 2));
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            message: "Success",
            data: updated.Attributes
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can we update dynamodb table based on index(not based on primary has and range key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886247/how-can-we-update-dynamodb-table-based-on-indexnot-based-on-primary-has-and-ran)

Answer (score -1):

All updates to items go against the Table, not any index. You will reference the item by the table primary key.